# Why are FTP connections read-only when I use "Connect to Server..."?

Tags: macos, finder, ftp

I'm just trying to connect to the server hosting my website through Finder, but it's always read only, even though I'm logging in with my username and password.

Obviously, I can connect with an FTP client (Fetch), and through the terminal, etc. – but what's the trick to FTP-uploading with Finder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21175?viewlocale=en_US):

> You can use the Connect To Server command to connect to an FTP server in the Finder, but you will have **read-only access. You cannot copy, or upload, to an FTP volume in the Finder.**

Comment: Good to know, I wasn't aware of this.