# Built in FTP client (cmd + k) - can't upload files (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, finder, ftp

I have just found out that I can enter a built-in FTP client on my Mac by simply pressing <kbd>^ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. Great thing!

But after I have successfully connected to my server and a 'folder' with files located there appeared, it occurred that I can't upload files by simply drag & drop'ing them. When I checked the 'Get info' I saw that it is marked as 'You can only read', yet the ftp account itself is okay, because I could upload files there from dreamweaver (unfortunately I have only Windows licence for this app).

Why is it marked as 'You can only read' and how do I fix that?

Please help!

P.S. Could you explain it in an easy way? Because I'm new to Mac (just bought one few days ago).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are FTP connections read-only when I use "Connect to Server..."?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/why-are-ftp-connections-read-only-when-i-use-connect-to-server)

Comment: Re dupe. I counter-flagged it, as this one has more info

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The built-in ftp is read only since forever unfortunately. From Mavericks help:

> Servers and shared computers that you can connect to
>
> You can connect your Mac to the types of servers and other computers
>   listed here.
>
> ...
>
> - FTP servers
>
> With read-only access, you can copy files from the server, but to copy
>   files to the server you may need another FTP app. Choose Apple menu >
>   App Store to find FTP apps available for OS X.

Maybe try the free [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io) or (not free) [Transmit](https://www.panic.com/transmit/).

Comment: Thanks :).
Btw. Why would I need an FTP client that could only read files ;___;?

Comment: Well, it's Apple, maybe this way they don't have to work too much on this "feature". Also see http://osxfuse.github.io and http://macfusionapp.org

Comment: Ok, MacFusionApp doesn't work with Mavericks, even the updated 2.0.5 version made by someone else. :(

Comment: ok, so just another mac bug. Think different!

Answer (score 9):

OS X builtin ftp client in Finder is read-only. I suggest you to use [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).

Answer (score 5):

The [FTP feature of Finder](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14098) only has Read-only access.

The possibilites you have :

- The command line `ftp` from the terminal
- [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io/), a Free App also available on the Mac App Store
- [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/), (my favourite) a 34$ FTP-App which has a nice feature : It can mount ftp servers like you can mount external drives.

Comment: Does macOS come with the `ftp` command? I get `-bash: ftp: command not found`.

Comment: It has been removed in the latest version (10.13)

Comment: @styfle: MacPorts and Homebrew allow for easy installation of command-line FTP clients, such as is included in GNU's inetutils.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions are:

- [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com) (open source, free, cross platform)
- [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/forklift/) (Mac App store, feature rich, sometimes it discounted to 1-2 bucks)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by just entering the web address into the entry box and leaving off the "ftp://" portion.
Logged in with the proper credentials and had read/write access.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of MacOS you are using, but on Yosemite a bare IP address is treated as a windows SMB share.

Comment: The domain the user was using likely supported both SMB and ftp

Answer (score 0):

Had to send a file for support, just used my ftp command on MacBooks Terminal.

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Enter: `ftp remote-ftp-address port`
   (ie. ftp hpsupport.com 21 )
3. Remote ftp server will ask you for credentials: *Name* first, then *Password*. In my case, credentials were: *anonymous / anonymous*
4. On "*Login successful*", you may enter any commands on lowercase and press RETURN to send:

   `ls`  (list directories / files on remote server)

   `cd remote-folder`  (to change current folder on remote server to some valid folder)

   `put local-file remote-file`
   (put command is to send a file. Must specify your local filename -the one you need to send- and name to send it to remote server.

In my case, I sent a file *support.zip* saved on my Downloads folder:

`put ~/Downloads/support.zip support.zip`

(you may use Tab to complete filename just after specify few letters of filename).

**HOW TO INSTALL FTP**
Just install *tnftp* with *brew*. In Terminal: `$ brew Install tnftp`

**HOW TO INSTALL HOMEBREW** (to use *brew* command)
If you don't have installed *Homebrew* (*brew* command), you may install it on **Terminal** with:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Monterey 12.4, MacBook M1 Pro 2021

Comment: How did you install the ftp binary?

Comment: Just install **tnftp** with **brew**. In **Terminal**:


**$ brew Install tnftp**

Comment: If you don't have installed Homebrew (brew command), you may install it on Terminal with: 

**/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"**

Comment: Shouldn‘t the point about installing the command be part of the answer then? Seems to be rather essential.

Comment: The original question is about ftp functionality only. You asked here, I tried to help you, that's all. The user that post the original request about functionality, is because have ftp already installed. The brew method is the most simple and, just in case, I also included hoy to install it. Hope it helps.

Comment: A user finding your answer will be lost after getting an „ftp: command not found“ error in the shell. Editing the download instructions directly into the answer would increase its usefulness.

Answer (score -3):

Mac FTP Instructions:

1) From the Finder menu, click Go, and then click “Connect to Server…”.

2) In the resulting dialog box, type in the FTP address: ftp://webaddress.com

3) Enter the user name and password provided

4) Once connected, a Finder window will open showing the contents of your FTP site.

5) To upload files or folders, just drag-and-drop them from your computer into the space provided.

Comment: This is the exact thing that doesn't work.