# Is there a way to write with FTP using the Finder

Tags: finder, ftp

I'm aware of this question [Built in FTP client (cmd + k) - can't upload files (Mavericks)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119519/built-in-ftp-client-cmd-k-cant-upload-files-mavericks), but my question is specifically targetted to anyone who has used Ubuntu, and fully understands how seamless FTP can be.

I'm looking to natively connect to an FTP server and be able to read and write. And open up folders in Atom or Sublime Text and just start editing files on the server.

Here are the options that I am aware of and have already tried, but none of them are as elegant as Ubuntu where you can just open a remote folder and start editing. If anyone knows of something, please let me know?

At the moment transit is the best option.
 - [Transit](https://panic.com/transmit/)

None of the others can edit whole folders in Sublime by importing the folder structure into the sidebar.
 - [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)
 - [Cyber Duck](https://cyberduck.io/)
 - [Forklift](https://www.google.co.za/search?num=50&safe=off&rlz=1C5CHFA_enZA784ZA784&ei=ApiMWqTKMceRgAaQ8bKgBA&q=forklift%20ftp&oq=forklift%20ftp&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5571.6073.0.6192.4.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.GdXcgqwPCzY)

Comment: What's wrong with Transmit (might want to [edit] that), I use it regularly for its Finder integration?

Comment: The reason why I don't like Transit, might be a little superficial but its because its not intuitive, I used it to copy a module update onto a server, I copied the whole modules folder and clicked overwrite and instead of just overwriting the folders that already exist, it left my modules folder only containing the new module... not a big deal, and something that can easily be avoided by clicking merge all first and then overwrite. But its just not intuitive in my opinion.

Comment: That's standard Finder behaviour, not anything to do with the client.

Comment: It's not standard in the files app on Ubuntu. Overwrite should merge folders and overwrite files, not delete the folder and add the new folder.

Comment: That's what merge is there for, I regularly use overwrite when I want to overwrite the entire folder. Anyway, my point is you're looking for FTP with Finder when your problem is actually with the way Finder works on macOS, completely unrelated to your choice of FTP client. What are you actually looking for?

Comment: Give me a second, I'll try Transit again and let you know why its not a adequate option for me

Comment: Okay, I can't take a whole theme folder and open it with Atom in order to import the whole folder structure of the theme into the Atom sidebar, so that I can jump through files from my text editor. I'm not saying that there aren't FTP clients on Mac that can technically do the job. I'm asking if anyone knows one on that works like Ubuntu. Seamless.

Comment: Why not? Works perfectly with Transmit. I do this all the time with other editors, and just downloaded Atom to prove it https://i.stack.imgur.com/No3bU.png

Comment: How do you get the whole folder to move from Transmit to Atom? If I right click no edit options come up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73456/discussion-between-grgarside-and-mark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finder only has read access to FTP so you need to use a client, but Transmit provides Finder integration so you can connect to FTP read/write using Finder with Transmit. You need to use the Finder integration.

1. Add the server to Transmit GUI as if you were connecting just using the GUI.
2. You can choose Mount as Disk to connect using Finder.

   [image]
3. To connect more easily in the future, show Transmit Disk in menu bar, which allows you to connect to servers in that list without Transmit running just using Finder.

   [image]

With the server mounted, you can work with files and folders as you would any local disk.

[image: Open in Atom]